# How to refer to Cocoa controls located in in the same NSWindow?

Tags: cocoa

I have a NSWindow with an NSView and an NSTextField inside.

I'm using Interface builder right now. I have dropped the two controls on the  default NSWindow and subclassed an NSView. I'm implementing the `-drawRect` method from NSView and I need to access to the content of NSTextField.

How do I refer to the instance of NSTextField from a method inside the NSView ?

Comment: Without proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/), it's impossible to answer this sort of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NSWindow is (or should be) controlled by a window controller. In IB you create an outlet for the NSTextField in your window controller. Using the outlet, you can then refer to the NSTextField:

In your window controller .h file:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;
```

In your window controller .m file:

```
@synthesize myTextField;
```

From there you can in your controller:

```
[[self myTextField] setEditable: NO];
```

A point to note is that you do not access the controls in a window directly from that window as windows (and all Cocoa controls for that matter) are statically stored in a XIB/NIB file. All access to controls (UI elements) is channelled through controllers (`NSWindowController`, `NSViewController`) which in turn are capable of loading XIB/NIB files.

Apple provides various samples in their docs on how to do this.